# postgres update the value of hstore with old partial value, in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, hstore

I've been trying to update the wrong migrated values of the hash store,

```
 "area_unit"=>NULL, "building_type"=>"{:building_type=>\"apartment\"}",
```

to

```
 "area_unit"=>NULL, "building_type"=>"apartment"}",
```

the value should stay the same, I don't want to use regular expression. is there an easy way for doing that ?  I'm working with ruby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do it like the following, not a generic solution like I wanted, but it works.

```
SELECT id, properties::hstore ->'building_type' FROM stops WHERE (properties->'building_type' like '{:building_type=>\"apartment\"}');

UPDATE stops SET properties = properties || '"building_type"=>"apartment"'::hstore
WHERE (properties->'building_type' like '{:building_type=>\"apartment\"}');
```